# Double face curve when using profile and bevel

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

[image]

I have a curve which I want to use as a profile. I also created a mesh object (not closed) similar to an open cylinder.

When I draw a new curve and apply the curve to taper object, and then apply the mesh as the bevel object I get a curve object with double faces.
What parameter should I adjust to fix it?

The curve below it´s how it should look correctly. (Second curve is just a mesh representation, not actual editable curve).

Comment: To be clear, is that mesh near the scene center the bevel object? Bevel objects need no depth: they're a path and shouldn't have faces. Also, this kind of thing can arise from using mirror modifiers on an object that is already symmetrical.

Comment: You´re correct. I solved this with a plain flat surface. Double faces were removed.